# Make an image where pixels are colored if they are prime

Tags: python, image, primes

This code creates a black-and-white image of variable size where the n-th pixel is white if n is a prime number and black if it isn't. It works, but I wonder if it is well written or if it could be made faster.

Example:

[image: Black-and-white image of variable size where the n-th pixel is white if n is a prime number]

Code:

```py
import math

from PIL import Image


def is_prime(num: int) -> bool:
    if not isinstance(num, int):
        raise TypeError("num must be integer!")
    if num < 2:
        return False
    if num == 2:
        return True
    for i in range(2, math.ceil(num ** 0.5) + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


def bw(i: int) -> tuple[int, int, int]:
    return (255 if is_prime(i) else 0,) * 3


def image(x_size: int, y_size: int = 0):
    if y_size == 0:
        y_size = x_size
    image = Image.new("RGB", (x_size, y_size), "black")
    for y in range(y_size):
        print(y * x_size)
        for x in range(x_size):
            image.putpixel((x, y), bw(x + y * x_size + 1))
    image.save("primes.png")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    image(1000)
```

Comment: Take a look at the questions under the tag [tag:sieve-of-eratosthenes].

Comment: That's a cool and beautiful visualization. Well done!

Comment: Only on my mobile here so I don't have an easy method to check the code, but why are there vertical black lines in the image every 5th column? Perhaps some nature of prime numbers in this context that I don't understand? Also, why are the white dots so small and rounded? I would have expected solid squares. Seems like the image resolution is higher than the amount of data pertinent to a number (pixel) being prime or not

Comment: @LamarLatrell: The image code generates an image 1000 pixels wide, which is a multiple of 5.  Hence all pixels in a column are congruent modulo 5, and those that are congruent to zero modulo 5 form columns of all black.  (The same should be true of 2, every second column should be entirely black.  Perhaps only black stripes of width 3, where a multiple of 5 falls between two multiples of 2 are wide enough to be visible.)

Comment: @BenVoigt, ahhh, thanks! I guess I would have chosen a prime width.

Comment: I can say for sure that the _image_ storage is inefficient; why are you storing a series of 1-bit values in a 24bpp format? `PIL.Image.new("1", (x_size, y_size), "black")` for a 1bpp black/white format (often used for masks), s'il vous plaît! Your file will be a tiny fraction of the size. Or at the very least, `PIL.Image.new("L", ...)` (for 8bpp grayscale).

Comment: I was occupied by writing my script so I failed to post an answer in time. Now I am late and there are already answers mentioning numpy and prime sieve... But they failed to mention that your image doesn't show the regularity of the prime gaps. If you use polar coordinates instead of Cartesian coordinates and put every number n at n radians and n distance from the origin, you will see patterns that your visualization failed to show. And if you create a new image using a different size, the relative location of the primes will change drastically, using polar coordinates will mitigate it.

Comment: Although I understand what it does and why, I find `(255 if is_prime(i) else 0,) * 3` a bit *too smart*. Multiplying a list instead of a tuple here might be a bit more readable.

Comment: Is the code correct? I would expect to see primes getting sparser as they get larger.

Answer (score 12):

There are some things I would comment on, outside of what [DeathIncarnate said in their answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/284348/151754).

---

The `is_prime` is fine, I would change two small details:

1. It is uncommon in Python to check the type of the input value (`if not isinstance(num, int)`). If the input is not an `int`, then all sorts of things are going wrong in the calling function. Is it really the responsibility of this function to avoid those? You could add an `assert`, [which can be disabled if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1273211/7328782). But mostly you should rely on the static type checking, which is what you have the type annotations for. This happens outside of executing the Python code, and therefore does not influence the execution speed.
2. The range `range(2, math.ceil(num ** 0.5) + 1)` is too wide. If `num**0.5` is not an integer, then the square of its ceil will be larger than `num`, and therefore does not need to be checked. You should use `math.floor` instead.

   But it generally contains too many numbers: if you can't divide by 2, you won't be able to divide by 4, 6, 8, ... This range could skip all even numbers. In fact, this range should skip all non-prime numbers, which is where my comment under your question hinted at.

The sieve of Erastothenes would be the standard way of producing a list of all primes up to a given number. It checks each new number to not be divisible by the primes found so far (in a manner of speaking, it actually doesn't use any divisions at all). In your case, you need a list of all primes up to and including `x_size * y_size`. Let's call this list `primes` (we'll come back to this later).

---

I agree with DeathIncarnate, you don't need an RGB image here, you just need a gray-scale image, which has a single channel. You can write a PNG of such a gray-scale image just fine. Because your code will be simpler, it is preferable.

To represent the image, I would use a NumPy array. Because NumPy arrays are easier to work with and more efficient to index than `PIL.Image` objects. Converting between the two is trivial, typically no data needs to be copied.

Earlier I referred `primes`, the list of primes. This list can be used to index into a NumPy array:

```py
import numpy as np

# ...

img = np.zeros((y_size, x_size), dtype=np.uint8)
img.reshape(-1)[primes] = 255
```

That's it, that's all you need to do to create your image.

...well, in your code you start counting pixels from 1, not 0 as I did there. To subtract 1 from your primes, you can convert the list to a NumPy array first:

```py
img.reshape(-1)[np.array(primes) - 1] = 255
```

Now, to save the image using Pillow, you can cast to a `PIL.Image`:

```py
Image.fromarray(img).save('primes.png')
```

---

I wanted to try these ideas out. [rdesparbes posted code with a better prime list generation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/284350/151754) similar to ideas I wrote above. This reduced the computation time on my machine from the 2.8s of OP's code to 0.63s. Using a NumPy array instead of a `PIL.Image` object, the time went down about 12%, to 0.55s. Implementing an actual sieve of Erastothenes (which doesn't do any divisions at all) reduced the time to 1/5th of that, 0.11s. This is about 25 times faster than OP's code.

This is the code I put together for testing. It's a bit messy, sorry for that, don't pay attention to the style, function names, or the functions themselves writing to file.

Note that about half of the 0.11s is converting the NumPy array to `PIL.Image`, and saving it to file.

```py
import math
import time

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


# --- OP ---


def is_prime(num: int) -> bool:
    if not isinstance(num, int):
        raise TypeError("num must be integer!")
    if num < 2:
        return False
    if num == 2:
        return True
    for i in range(2, math.ceil(num ** 0.5) + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


def bw(i: int) -> tuple[int, int, int]:
    return (255 if is_prime(i) else 0,) * 3


def original_image(x_size: int, y_size: int = 0):
    if y_size == 0:
        y_size = x_size
    image = Image.new("RGB", (x_size, y_size), "black")
    for y in range(y_size):
        for x in range(x_size):
            image.putpixel((x, y), bw(x + y * x_size + 1))
    image.save("original_image.png")


# --- RDESPARBES https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/284350/151754 ---


def compute_primes(maximum: int) -> list[int]:
    # updated by Cris to not test even numbers, and a few other tweaks
    if maximum <= 2:
        return []
    primes = [2]

    def is_prime(number_to_test_: int) -> bool:
        max_threshold = int(number_to_test_ ** 0.5)
        for prime in primes:
            if prime > max_threshold:
                break
            if number_to_test_ % prime == 0:
                return False
        return True

    for number_to_test in range(3, maximum, 2):
        if is_prime(number_to_test):
            primes.append(number_to_test)
    return primes


def rdesparbes_image(x_size: int, y_size: int | None = None) -> None:
    if y_size is None:
        y_size = x_size
    primes: list[int] = compute_primes(maximum=x_size * y_size + 1)  # fixed upper limit!
    image = Image.new("RGB", (x_size, y_size), "black")
    for prime in primes:
        y, x = divmod(prime - 1, x_size)
        image.putpixel((x, y), (255, 255, 255))
    image.save("rdesparbes_image.png")


# --- CRIS #1: like above, but using NumPy array ---


def better_image(x_size: int, y_size: int | None = None) -> None:
    if y_size is None:
        y_size = x_size
    primes = compute_primes(x_size * y_size + 1)
    img = np.zeros((y_size, x_size), dtype=np.uint8)
    img.reshape(-1)[np.array(primes) - 1] = 255
    Image.fromarray(img).save('better_image.png')
    

# --- CRIS #2: sieve of Erastothenes ---


def sieve_image(x_size: int, y_size: int | None = None) -> None:
    if y_size is None:
        y_size = x_size
    primes = np.ones(x_size * y_size + 1, dtype=np.bool_)
    primes[0:2] = False
    for ii in range(2, len(primes)):
        if primes[ii]:
            primes[ii**2::ii] = False
    primes = np.reshape(primes[1:], (y_size, x_size)).astype(np.uint8)
    primes *= 255
    Image.fromarray(primes).save('sieve_image.png')


# --- MAIN ---


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = time.time()
    original_image(1000)
    print(f"{time.time() - t:0.3f}s")

    t = time.time()
    rdesparbes_image(1000)
    print(f"{time.time() - t:0.3f}s")
    
    t = time.time()
    better_image(1000)
    print(f"{time.time() - t:0.3f}s")

    t = time.time()
    sieve_image(1000)
    print(f"{time.time() - t:0.3f}s")
```

Comment: Would it be easier to work with a 1-D array and reshape it just before converting to an image?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, you could replace `img = np.zeros((y_size, x_size), dtype=np.uint8); img.reshape(-1)[primes] = 255` with `img = np.zeros((y_size * x_size), dtype=np.uint8); img[primes] = 255; img = np.reshape(img, (y_size, x_size))`. Either way is quite simple, I think. :)

Comment: Ah I see, I missed that `primes` was *already* a 1-D array.  Carry on.

Comment: Observation:   A while back I did some speed testing on the Sieve and found that it was a bad idea as far along as I tested--main memory hits are far more expensive than divisions.  It made sense in the old days when division was expensive and memory hits weren't nearly as bad.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Here we just do primes up to 1 million, it seems that the sieve performs very well in this range. See the update, I added some code and timing at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It's fast, I'm just saying that when I compared it with simply testing against each number was faster.  The sieve basically replaces division with addition + memory write, performing the same number of operations.  For a human that's a vast improvement, but on a modern CPU the memory write is much more expensive than the division.

Comment: @LorenPechtel in the test I added to this post, it’s much faster than division. Part of that difference might be replacing Python loops with built-in NumPy operations. And maybe the relative speeds are different for larger arrays. The experiment above only goes up to 1M.

Answer (score 9):

Now, I will preface this by saying I've never used `pillow` before, so this is likely not the most effective means of doing this.

### Docstrings

You have used type annotations well in your functions which is a good start, but you may want to look into adding docstrings to describe their function.

### Arguments

Why do you default `y_size` to `0`, as your not-entered? It is more idiomatic to use `None` (you may choose `-1` if you want to avoid `None`) as a not supplied value rather than something which is potentially "valid". Consider if I was automating using this I could imagine a scenario where I requested a `0` element image (of course if I requested a `-1` sized image that should probably error out)

Also, you don't allow the user to write to a file of their choosing. You should probably pass that as an argument through to the function to avoid users having to manually update their code or accidentally overwriting different sized images.

### Shadowing

The main `image` variable inside your function has the same name as the function itself which is not a good thing and could lead to confusion. It is common practice to give functions names which are verbs such as `generate_image`, even this is a little generic and you might want `generate_primes_image`

### Image Type

You create a full RGB image while `pillow` offers a convenient [bitwise image](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) which seems to be what you want. Additionally, with the bitmap we would no longer need `bw` and simply `is_prime` can be our generator.

The `pillow` documentation also notes:

> Image.putpixel(xy, value)[source]
>
> Modifies the pixel at the given position. The color is given as a single numerical value for single-band images, and a tuple for multi-band images. In addition to this, RGB and RGBA tuples are accepted for P and PA images.
>
> Note that this method is relatively slow. For more extensive changes, use paste() or the ImageDraw module instead.

So we probably might want to look at other means of generating it.

### Using generators

Looking into the documentation it seems we can generate our image more efficiently by running the loops as a generator:

```
def generate_primes_image(x_size: int, y_size: int = None, output_file: str = "primes.png"):
    """ Generates a pixel representation of the primes as a 2d image saved to 
        `output_file`     
    """
    if y_size is None:
        y_size = x_size

    # Using 255*is_prime because this packs to length-8 bytes
    # mode is greyscale ("L") to match 
    u = (is_prime(x)*255 for x in range(1, (x_size*y_size)+1))
    image = Image.frombytes("L", (x_size, y_size), bytes(u))
    image.save(output_file)
```

This should actually generate the data through C all at once which should be more efficient.

You could also look at the Sieve of Erastothenes (as suggested in the comments) or other prime generating methods and use the `ImageDraw` module to modify chunks of the image as you find the elements which are not prime.

Comment: A good answer, except I don't see how `y_size==0` could be a legal value. An image without pixels is not an image.

Comment: It's true that it only writes out an empty image, but I would still argue it's an image, just as an empty list is still a list. Certainly up to taste (and what's supported by `pillow`). I would also say that `None` (or a definitely illegal value such as `-1`) is more definitively "empty".

Comment: I agree, I would definitely choose `None` there.

Comment: I just tried this out, it seems that Pillow will happily create an `Image` object where one dimension is 0 (ridiculous!). But if you try to save that as a PNG, it will error out (no image file formats that I know of support images with zero pixels, this is not exclusive to PNG).

Comment: `pnm` probably would, but yeah, not worth arguing. It's very situation dependent, but if it were to be a library I would probably support an early return on 0, or dumping an empty file, just because I can envision someone (probably through automation) requesting no primes.

Comment: [Arguments] The canonical way to detect defaulted arguments is to create a sentinel value (the Python docs suggest an `object()` instance, I prefer a bare `class`), and use that as your default value: `class NoY: pass; def image(x: int, y = NoY, ...):`. If `y` is anything other than `NoY`, even `None`, it's a value the user passed in. ...Where the type makes a difference is in the signature. With `NoY = object()`, `help(image)` gives you `image(x: int, y=<object object at 0x7f2c5efa8620>)` (ugh). `class NoY` gets you `image(x: int, y=<class 'module.NoY'>)` (self-documenting!)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I imagine `PIL` allows `0`-dimension images because it has tools like `PIL.Image.Image.paste()` — if you're assembling an image programmatically by pasting sections cropped from elsewhere (or generated outright), it's theoretically possible that you might occasionally end up taking/generating a no-sized section to insert — calling `dest.paste(no_size_image)` is a lot better than accidentally calling `dest.paste(None)` and taking home a traceback for your troubles.

Answer (score 8):

## Style and design

```py
if not isinstance(num, int):
    raise TypeError("num must be integer!")
```

This piece of code is not really necessary: the type annotation makes it clear that you expect an `int` here.
If you are worried about what the user of this function could provide as an argument, you can add a docstring,
or use a static type checker like [mypy](https://mypy-lang.org/)

```py
def image(x_size: int, y_size: int = 0):
    if y_size == 0:
        y_size = x_size
```

- This behavior could be described in a docstring, as it is not obvious from the signature of the function itself.
- Also, on a more general note, good job on adding type annotations. But it's a good practice to also indicate
  that a function does not return anything with `-> None:`.
- `image` is a confusing name for a function. Usually, functions start with a verb. This function's name conflicts
  with the name of the actual `Image.Image` instance. `compute_image` or `generate_prime_image` would
  probably be a better name for this function.

### Split responsibilities

```py
image.save("primes.png")
```

This part makes the `image` function hard to reuse in another context, and should probably be moved elsewhere.

## Performance

This script is slow for two main reasons:

- The `print` statement, which makes expensive system calls
- Primes that have already been computed could be reused to compute new primes
  (see [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes))

## Refactoring

Here is another version of the script that shows the same behavior, but is apparently faster because
prime numbers are saved and reused to compute new ones:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import math

from PIL import Image


def compute_primes(maximum: int) -> List[int]:
    """Compute the list of the prime number

    :param maximum: Upper bound of the list, not included
    :return: The prime numbers, in ascending order
    """
    if maximum <= 2:
        return []
    primes: List[int] = []

    def is_prime(number_to_test_: int) -> bool:
        max_threshold: int = math.ceil(number_to_test_ ** 0.5) + 1
        for prime in primes:
            if prime >= max_threshold:
                break
            if number_to_test_ % prime == 0:
                return False
        return True

    for number_to_test in range(2, maximum):
        if is_prime(number_to_test):
            primes.append(number_to_test)
    return primes


def generate_prime_image(x_size: int, y_size: int | None = None) -> Image.Image:
    if y_size is None:
        y_size = x_size
    primes: list[int] = compute_primes(maximum=x_size * y_size)
    image = Image.new("RGB", (x_size, y_size), "black")
    for prime in primes:
        y, x = divmod(prime - 1, x_size)
        image.putpixel((x, y), (255, 255, 255))
    return image


def main() -> None:
    image = generate_prime_image(1000)
    image.save("primes.png")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I would probably argue that you might want `primes` to be a `set` rather than a `list` for fast indexing although you're just looping over it and not reusing it so not necessary. I'm also a little confused why you're defining `is_prime` in the loop, is that an indentation issue from SE formatting?

Comment: We do not need to check if an element is present in the `primes` collection, so there is no need to use a `set`. `list`s are usually faster and more memory efficient (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17945009/17674349)
`is_prime` is an inner function confined to the scope of the `compute_primes` function, as it is tightly coupled to it; it needs a read-only access to the `primes` list in a very specific state, which makes it hard to reuse if we defined it as a standard function. The `prime` function could be inlined, but I found it less readable

Comment: You can `def` the function once outside the loop and it would still have access to the variables in the function scope.

Comment: Oh yes indeed! I will modify my answer.
(for those who are interested, I performed a benchmark with `timeit`, and measured a ~20% increase in speed when the function definition is outside the loop, which totally make sense...)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a Python "expert", but, I hope you appreciate what I have to say.

---

Besides everything that was said, I do see 2 issues with your code:

## 1 - You have a magic number

You have the following lines:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    image(1000)
```

You could use the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module to receive the size as an argument.

Here's my example on how it can be implemented:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog="Some Program name here",
        description="Generates a black-and-white image of variable size where the n-th pixel is white if n is a prime number and black if it isn't."
    )
    
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--size", type=int, default=1000)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    image(args.size)
```

---

## 2 - The image name and path are hardcoded

This makes it pretty inflexible to use.

You can change your `image` function to have the following:

```py
def image(x_size: int, y_size: int = 0, fp = "primes.png"):
    [...]
    image.save(fp)
```

Then, you can modify the code I gave you before, to allow passing a file name:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog="Some Program name here",
        description="Generates a black-and-white image of variable size where the n-th pixel is white if n is a prime number and black if it isn't."
    )
    
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--size", type=int, default=1000)
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", type=str, default="primes.png")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    image(args.size, fp=args.filename)
```

---

This basically allows you to actually make something useful out of that `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

You can just run it like this: `python3 file.py --size=2500 --file="huge.jpg"`.